# How to change text style in iPhone / iPad Album categories?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, photo

so basically I have two apps that use iPhone and iPad photo libraries (albums). When I go to get the image from the phone's album on one app, I get normal album fonts (Camera Roll, Animals, People... ) whereas when I open the other app I get the same list of albums but the names are much bolder. Is there a way to change this so they get to the default font again ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom View which will just be like the Photo Library but with customized appearance. You cannot modify the Apple's Official Library fonts and styles.

You have to create your own custom Library View.

Comment: Hey Rajan, Thanks for your reply. just a question... how is it possible that the other app has the normal font, whilst the other one has bold when both of them use regular apple library.

Comment: Can you tell me , which app you are saying ?

Comment: Well, my client has 2 different apps, similar in niche, both built by the same team, just have different album fonts, which is a bug.

Comment: I can't say anything without seeing the app. I hope you can understand.